# Java: XSLT with output HTML but without HTML entities

Tags: java, html, xslt, entities

Is it possible to to a XSL transformation mit xsl:output method set to HTML but without using HTML entities in the output? The output should either use numeric entities or no entities at all (as i am using UTF-8 entities are not required).

Comment: Why do you care? As long as the output is well-formed HTML, the details shouldn't matter.

Comment: I have to process the result further where no HTML entities are understood. Output as XML is not possible either as self closing tags are not supported. I am not able to change the processing code.

Comment: And right there's your problem. Don't feed HTML to a component that does not understand HTML. Change that component to use an HTML parser or if that's impossible create a new component that pre-processes the HTML accordingly. You current approach is not... wise and you should spend your time trying to do the Right Thing, instead of trying to do the Wrong Thing properly.

Comment: It always depends on the time needed. If it would have been a simple setting to disable html entities which is about 1 minute of work it is not wise to rewrite components which would take days. But nonetheless thanks for your reply. I already thought that it would not be a simple setting.

Comment: If you want to output plain text, do that instead. There are no character entities in text. That HTML-but-not-HTML thing is futile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `disable-output-escaping`. Using this input:

```
<test>Café</test>
```

with this XSL stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="test">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will render:

```
<test>Caf&eacute;</test>
```

But if you add `disable-output-escaping="yes"` to `<xsl:value-of>`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

you get:

```
<test>Café</test>
```

You might also get unescaped HTML if you use a transformer that doesn't escape HTML by default, such as Saxon 9. I also believe you can configure Xalan to not escape HTML entities by default.

You can try a different transformer which disables output escaping by default.

Comment: Thanks. This also helps to output non-latin characters in e.g. German text as-is, saving quite a bit of bandwidth.